# Qsettings, how to save an empty list

Tags: pyqt, qsettings

When you use QSettings IniFormat, an empty list is stored in the .ini file as @Invalid().
When you retrieve the value, you get 'None'. This obviously can cause problem when you expect a list.

Using defaultValue=[] doesn't help, you still get None.

As a workaround you can do something like

```
foo = settings.value('my_list) or []
```

But is there also a way to retrieve an empty list directly from the .ini file?

It could be that this is only an issue on Windows. (see https://github.com/frescobaldi/frescobaldi/issues/1137)

Comment: This is a Windows issue (it works fine for me on Linux). Do you get a type-error when trying `settings.value('my_list', [], list)`? If so, try `settings.value('my_list', [], 'QVariantList')` instead.

Comment: @ekhumoro, settings.value('my_list', [], list) does the trick. What is that third argument? I don't see it documented.

Comment: It's a type-hint. See the PyQt docs: [Support for QSettings](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt_qsettings.html).

Comment: Ah, It's a python-only thing, I should use the pyqt docs more often instead of just the c++ docs. Thanks

Comment: @mahkitah just use them when in doubt about function arguments and returned values just like in your case (it's a known fact that the PyQt docs are not well maintained), otherwise the standard C++ docs are fine 99.9% of the times. It's also quite enough to just call `help(class.function)` in the python interactive shell.